# How to get named list of arguments from fmt::format_args

Tags: fmt

I'm trying to build C++ logging integration for Logz.IO which uses named parameters for string interpolation and I'd like to leverage `fmt` for argument parsing and formatting. Essentially I'm trying to build function that will allow me to pass named arguments e.g.

```
log_fmt("Length: {Length:.2f}", fmt::arg("Length", 125.5f));
```

I followed documentation to build templated function and my own logging function:

```
  template <typename S, typename... Args>
  void log_fmt(const S& format, Args&&... args) {
    vlog(level, format,
         fmt::make_args_checked<Args...>(format, args...));
  }

  void vlog(fmt::string_view format, fmt::format_args args) {}
```

Inside my implementation of `vlog` I would like to convert `args` to JSON object that will contain all arguments (ideally without formatting part):

```
{
    "Length": 125.5
}
```

However it looks like `format_args` exposes only very basic public interface (only allowing to `get`. How can I iterate over `args` and get each argument name and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{fmt} doesn't provide an API to iterate over named arguments but you can do it yourself in `log_fmt`. Each named argument will have [the following type](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/c71b070168b74bdd31d0bbd873a404b800bd4ea6/include/fmt/core.h#L1027-L1031):

```cpp
template <typename Char, typename T> struct named_arg : view {
  const Char* name;
  const T& value;
  named_arg(const Char* n, const T& v) : name(n), value(v) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I ended up using this with nlohmann::json:

```
template <typename T>
  void convertArgs(nlohmann::json& data, const T& t) {
    data[t.name] = t.value;
  }

template <typename S, typename... Args>
  void log_fmt(const S& format, Args&&... args) {
    nlohmann::json data;
    convertArgs(data, args...);

    // Pass data to logger
}
```